# Three.js Cube different textures

Tags: three.js

I have a Problem with different textures on a cube. It only takes 1 texture with the following code...

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture1 = texture.load('texture1.jpg');
var texture2 = texture.load('texture2.jpg');
var texture3 = texture.load('texture3.jpg');
var texture4 = texture.load('texture4.jpg');
var texture5 = texture.load('texture5.jpg');
var texture6 = texture.load('texture6.jpg');
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(height,width,length);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture1, 
                    map: texture2,map: texture3,map: texture4,map: texture5,
                    map: texture6 } );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(height,width,length);

var materials = [
           new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture1.jpg')
           }),
           new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture2.jpg')
           }),
           new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture3.jpg')
           }),
           new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture4.jpg')
           }),
           new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture5.jpg')
           }),
           new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('texture6.jpg')
           })
];

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
scene.add(mesh);
```